# Wireshark's monitoring method type

Tags: wireshark

Is Network traffic monitoring with WireShark:

- Active Monitoring
- Passive Monitoring
- Combinational Monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark performs passive monitoring.  It would likely help you to know what the differences are.

*Passive* monitoring indicates that a network device has been put into promiscuous mode and begins collecting network frames as they pass by, making them available for analysis.

*Active* monitoring indicates that some sort of stimulation is generated by the tool performing the monitoring.  An example would be broadcasting out a large number of SSIDs to attempt to stimulate a response from a wireless network device.

Comment: And if you want Wireshark to be completely passive, then you should disable name resolution to avoid DNS lookups being generated by Wireshark.  Also, if you're on Windows, you should disable automatic updates so Wireshark doesn't attempt to check if a new version of Wireshark is available when it starts.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard Good point.  I didn't think of that since I always have it disabled by default. ;)